# IOS/ safari, Skeljs side navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, wordpress

I decided to use an HTML5up template (Verti => [here](http://html5up.net/verti)) as the basis for a WordPress theme for a client. The client needed me to deploy early, so the site is live=> [here](http://culinarycraft.catering). The side navigation doesn't work on IOS/ safari, or Chrome on an iPhone. Those are the only browsers with problems

Here's the javascript called in the footer:

```
$('.banner').unslider({
            arrows: true,
            fluid: true,
            dots: true,
            fade:true
        });

        //  Find any element starting with a # in the URL
        //  And listen to any click events it fires

        $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
            //  Find the target element
            var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
            //  And get its position
            var pos = target.offset(); // fallback to scrolling to top || {left: 0, top: 0};
            //  jQuery will return false if there's no element
            //  and your code will throw errors if it tries to do .offset().left;
            if(pos) {
                //  Scroll the page
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: pos.top,
                    scrollLeft: pos.left
                }, 1000);
            }
            //  Don't let them visit the url, we'll scroll you there
            return false;
        });    
$("#mygallery").justifiedGallery({
     rowHeight : 160
     });
```

And here's the navigation:

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
            <header id="header" class="container">              
                <!-- Logo -->
                    <div id="logo">
                        <h1><a href="index.html">Culinary Craft</a></h1>
                        <span>Catering Co.</span>
                    </div>

                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/our-services/">Services</a>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/our-services/">Services</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/our-services">Catering</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/liquid-catering">Liquid Catering</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/corporate-events">Weddings and Corporate Events</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>

                                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/planning">Planning</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/execution">Execution</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/menus">Menus</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/about">About</a>
                                <ul>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/why-culinary-craft">Why Culinary Craft?</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/about">Our Executive Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/frequently-asked-questions">Frequently Asked questions</a></li>
                                <!--<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">Orange County</a></li>-->
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

            </header>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to figure out why the nav wouldn't work, but only for these specific browsers.

Comment: You should check the web dev console, there are 2 js-errors: `unslider` and `justifiedGallery` is not a function (for both). Maybe fixing this will help.

Comment: Side navigation? Did you mean site navigation?

Comment: Guess I just found it (at least for the errors), it should help if you wrap the inline js like e.g. `$("#mygallery").justifiedGallery(..` in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: yea... I saw those... they are related to different parts of the site, and when I originally was trying to debug the error I just pulled them to see what would happen and the Nav still wasn't working. but you're definitely right that i should really fix those before I ask for help. My apologies... I'll get it right now

Comment: I just updated the jquery to have a $(document).ready  and it broke the site... so I'm going to leave it for a bit so people can see

Comment: You mean fixing the errors made it somehow worse? If so, in which way? Only thing I'm noticing is that some webfonts are not loaded (e.g. for the social media icons at the footer or for the menu when minimizing the window for mobile view) that are related to fontawesome (fontawesome-webfont.ttf and .woff) as they are referenced to be loaded from a different domain (stormclouddevelopment.info) that blocks the request.

Comment: The updated code messed up the slide show... I haven't caught any other errors related to the document ready